# get ride from .0 for all elements of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file and i read it with this function :

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"\test.csv", sep=';')
```

and to fill NaN with -99 using

```
data = data.fillna(-99)
```

but i get at the end the dataframe :

```
202       5092019  ...              2.7            -99.0
```

so i need to get ride from all .0 from all elements that i have so i get that :

```
202460618       5092019  ...              2.7            -99
```

Doese any one have a suggest ?
Should i provide more informations.
thanks a lot

Comment: `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply . The problem is that there is a floats and strings in my dataframe so if did that i will get for the value 2.7 a value of 2 right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = data.fillna(int(-99))
```

Comment: This is actually not different from what is already present in question

Answer (score 0):

fillna() takes an obscure argument called downcast, which you can set equal to 'infer' to do what you need here.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df) #0    3  NaN  4.5  NaN  3.2 NaN

df.fillna(-99, inplace=True, downcast='infer')
print(df )#0    3  -99  4.5  -99  3.2 -99
```